# Find the dimension and a basis of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $U$ is the set of all commuting matrices with matrix $A=        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        3 & 0 & 4 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$. Prove that $U$ is the subspace of $\mathbb{M_{3\times 3}}$ (space of matrices $3\times 3$). Check if it contains $span\{I,A,A^2,...\}$. Find the dimension and a basis for given subspaces.

$U$ can be defined as $U=\{B\in\mathbb{M_{3\times 3}}: AB=BA\}$.

Letting $B=\begin{bmatrix}
        a & b & c \\
        d & e & f \\
        g & h & i \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ and solving the equation $AB=BA$ gives $B=\begin{bmatrix}
        i-\frac{2}{3}g & 0 & \frac{1}{3}g \\
        g-3f & i-3g & f \\
        g & 0 & i \\
        \end{bmatrix}$.

$U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{M_{3\times3}}$ if $\forall u_1,u_2\in U\Rightarrow u_1+u_2\in U,\forall t\in\mathbb{R}\Rightarrow tu_1\in U$ which is correct.

Question: How to check if $U$ contains $span\{I,A,A^2,...\}$?

Linear combination gives $\begin{bmatrix}
        i-\frac{2}{3}g & 0 & \frac{1}{3}g \\
        g-3f & i-3g & f \\
        g & 0 & i \\
        \end{bmatrix}=c_1\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}+c_2\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        3 & 0 & 4 \\
        \end{bmatrix}+...+c_nA^n$

How to determine if this system is solvable?

$U$ has the dimension $3$ and a basis are column vectors of identity matrix $3\times 3$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prove that if $C\in span\{I, A, A^2, ...\}$ then $C\in U$.

But then $C=c_0I+c_1A+c_2A^2+\dots$

and

$CA = c_0IA+c_1AA+c_2A^2A+\dots = c_0AI+c_1AA+c_2AA^2+\dots = AC$

QED